# Search for job titles in an article using Spacy or NLTK

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I'm new to NLP and recently been playing with NTLK and Spacy. However, I could not find a way to search for job titles (ex: product manager, chief marketing officer, etc) in an article.

Example, I have 1000 articles and I want to get all the articles that have job titles that I am interested in.

Also, what entity type does job titles fall in? I check https://spacy.io/docs/usage/entity-recognition and did not see it in there. I there a plan to add it?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, job title in the limited context you mention is some type of NE, but I believe you would have to know what words you are looking for, or specific features that you would like to capture

Comment: a job title is a type of NP POS tag which is usually an ORG related entity tag. Basically it sounds like you want a job title tagger. You may want to try and make a list of job titles, and extract features for those job titles then make a tagger yourself. Will work better for your domain of knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

"Job Titles" entity is not supported by Spacy NER, as also stated by [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934851/nathan-mccoy). But you can create a custom named entity for your use case. Here is official documentation [link](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-typetrain_new_entity_type.py). You can find step by step guide to train Spacy NER there.

You would need labeled data to train your NER. Generally you would need atleast 4000-5000 examples for train and 2000 examples for test. The more training data you have, the better will be the NER performance.

Here is some sample training data.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ('Who is Shaka Khan?', {
        'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]
    }),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', {
        'entities': [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')]
    }),
    ('I work as software engineer.', {
        'entities': [(9, 18, 'JOBTITLE')]
    }),

]
```

Answer (score 2):

Stanford NER supports Titles (not perfect though). See demo page at http://corenlp.run/