# return job titile from text string

Tags: python, spacy

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

file_path = "insurance_data.csv"
original_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

def extract_job_title(user_input):
    
    user_input = user_input.lower()

    job_titles = original_df["job_title"].unique()
    for job_title in job_titles:
        if job_title.lower() in user_input:
            print(job_title)
            return job_title
        else:
            nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

            doc = nlp(user_input)

            job_titles = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == "ORG" or ent.label_ == "TITLE"]

            if job_titles:
                print(job_titles)
                return job_titles[-1]
            else:
                print("Can't understand. Please provide a valid job title.")

user_input = 'i am a Doctor'
a = extract_job_title(user_input)
print(a)
```

I encountered an issue while using Spacy to identify job titles in my array. It seems that 'doctor' is not being recognized as a valid job title. Could you please suggest an alternative job title for accurate processing?

I want to find Job title even if its not in my array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for job titles in an article using Spacy or NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400920/search-for-job-titles-in-an-article-using-spacy-or-nltk)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Did I understand correctly that `original_df["job_title"].unique()` does not contain a title "Doctor"?

`ORG` is a label for "Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.", so not job titles, and there's no such thing as `TITLE` in the default entity labels, unless you train it yourself with custom data.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185150/return-all-possible-entity-types-from-spacy-model), the existing labels are:

```
['ORG', 'CARDINAL', 'DATE', 'GPE', 'PERSON', 'MONEY', 'PRODUCT', 'TIME', 'PERCENT', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'QUANTITY', 'NORP', 'LOC', 'EVENT', 'ORDINAL', 'FAC', 'LAW', 'LANGUAGE']
```

You can find the descriptions for each label from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/curiousprogrammer/entity-extraction-and-classification-using-spacy), but none of those includes job titles. This means you are out of luck and need to train your own `EntityRecognizer`. There's tutorials of that in the internet, but you will need training data of course.

### Other problems

Even if your spacy code would work, it would be terrible inefficient to run it inside your for loop. Move it out of it, so it will only run once after you have checked your existence in `job_titles`.

Comment: yes original_df["job_title"].unique() does not contain a title "Doctor" did you know any other way to recognize job-titles

Comment: Nothing that involves a custom training data. Seems that this has been asked before too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400920/search-for-job-titles-in-an-article-using-spacy-or-nltk, though there might be some new developments since 2018.